# Windows Ubuntu Terminal Script not Working

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

for my bash programming assignment i have to create pipelines to process a file to find some patterns. I am currently using the **Windows 10 Ubuntu App** terminal.  I Wrote the following the following :

```
echo "Processing Log Files..."
# error is the word I'm looking for in the files
grep error -A 1 logfile1.txt >> filter.txt
grep error -A 1 logfile2.txt >> filter.txt
echo "Done."
```

But when i run the file with the header **#!/bin/sh** I get this error:

```
Processing Log Files...
: Directory nonexistentoder.sh: cannot create filter.txt
: Directory nonexistentoder.sh: cannot create filter.txt
Done.
```

And when i run the code with the header **#!/bin/bash** i get this error:

```
Processing Log Files...
: No such file or directoryer.txt
: No such file or directoryer.txt
Done.
```

I honestly have no idea of why this happens, i changed the permissions of the files to the following:

```
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root   512 Mar 20 23:25 .
drwxrwxrwx 0 root root   512 Mar 20 13:59 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   316 Mar 20 23:24 decoder.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52247 Mar 19 15:59 logfile1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33142 Mar 19 15:59 logfile2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   239 Mar 19 15:39 mapping-sorted.txt
```

Comment: Are you running the script as root or as a user ?

Comment: Whenever you see text smooshed together like `directoryer.txt` the most likely issue is that the script has been created/saved with Windows line endings (CR/LF rather than plain LF)

Comment: @steeldriver That might be the issue since in edition the files using a windows program, rather than a terminal editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @steeldriver I found out that the script i wrote had hidden windows characters, since i was using a windows text editor. I ran the following line, and the file had the header **#!/bin/bash**.

```
dos2unix scriptName.sh
```

the script worked afterwards :D